# Pass Shell Arguments to Boto3 Python with argparse

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, argparse, boto3

I'm trying to pass shell arguments into a python script, but I need to be able to append what comes into argparse as well.

The shell command will be

```
python script.py $arg1 $arg2
```

script.py is

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('my-bucket').upload_file(print 'sys.argv[1]', print 'sys.argv[2]')
```

EDIT

In some cases the $arg will need to add filetype or directory.

Comment: Please clarify "need to be able to append what comes into argparse"

Comment: `upload_file(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])`?

Comment: @wim some of the args will need filetype, directory, or other info added to it. I wasn't sure when that would be placed into the call.

Comment: I started answering this but really you are confused about the basics of how python works and I am not sure where to begin.  I suggest you review a basic course on python such as https://www.learnpython.org/

Answer (score 0):

**You can Pass Shell Arguments to Boto3 Python with argparse as follows**:

```
import argparse
import boto3
import botocore
import os
import pandas as pd
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig

def environment_set(access_key,secret_access_key):
    os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = access_key
    os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = secret_access_key

def s3_upload_file(args):     
    while True:
    try:
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

        GB = 1024 ** 3

            # Ensure that multipart uploads only happen if the size of a transfer
            # is larger than S3's size limit for nonmultipart uploads, which is 5 GB.
            config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=5 * GB)

        s3.meta.client.upload_file(args.path, args.bucket, os.path.basename(args.path),Config=config)
        print "S3 Uploading successful"
        break
    except botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError:
        print "Network Error: Please Check your Internet Connection"
    except Exception, e:
        print e


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='UPLOAD A FILE TO PRE-EXISTING S3 BUCKET')
    parser.add_argument('path', metavar='PATH', type=str,
            help='Enter the Path to file to be uploaded to s3')
    parser.add_argument('bucket', metavar='BUCKET_NAME', type=str,
            help='Enter the name of the bucket to which file has to be uploaded')
    parser.add_argument('cred', metavar='CREDENTIALS', type=str,
            help='Enter the Path to credentials.csv, having AWS access key and secret access key')    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    df = pd.read_csv(args.cred, header=None)
    access_key = df.iloc[1,1]
    secret_access_key = df.iloc[1,2]
    environment_set(access_key,secret_access_key)
    s3_upload_file(args)
```

when it comes to appending, basic python should help you!